# Why didn't the Tesseract get transported with Red Skull?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers, captain-america-the-first-avenger

At the end of **Captain America: The First Avenger** Red Skull disappears and it was later discovered that he was transported by the Tesseract. In other circumstances like when Thor took Loki to Asgard at the end of **The Avengers**, the Tesseract went with them. But in case of Red Skull he was transported but the Tesseract didn't go with him. Why did this happen?

Comment: @A J I know that Red Skull is alive. But why didn't the Tesseract got transported with him like others?

Comment: please see the answer to the marked question

Comment: @asHK How can Tesseract banish someone? It surely doesn't have any mind?

Comment: At the end of Avengers they didn't use the space stone to travel to Asgard, but the Bifrost. Presumably they made an appointment with Heimdall because Thor could not yet control the Bifrost then. The Tesseract was just luggage he brought along.

Comment: @Jacco Amersfoort I think you're wrong. Whenever they use bifrost, I pattern appears under them which didn't appear at the end of avengers.